# Multipage Gui in Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, multipage

I'm building a gui in matlab.
I wanted to create with mutually exclusive radio buttons that, when selected, bring the user to a different page.

How can I include multiple pages in a single gui?

Thank you

Comment: Another option is to use tabbed pages, which you can do pretty easily using the GUI Layout Toolbox. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27758-gui-layout-toolbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the controls for each page in a `uipanel`, put all the panels in the same position, then have the radio buttons set the `Visible` property on all of them appropriately, such that only one is ever displayed.

Note you *only* need to toggle the `uipanel` - if you hide one, all its children are hidden regardless of their own `Visible` properties.